# How to format as UTC string with date-fns library?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

In date-fns library I do this

```
var from = new Date();
format(from, "MMMM d, yyyy");
```

However this gives me the localized value similarly as to if I did `new Date().toString()`. I am looking for the equivalent of `new Date().toUTCString()`. How can I format in date-fns to UTC string?

Comment: Why would you need to find the equivalent of something that's already built in?

Comment: To get it outputted to a certain format i.e. "MMMM d, yyyy"

Comment: For JavaScript Date formatting, take a look at this question over here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Thats a lot of manual parsing, a bit of stone age. If it was 1 function call with a formatter string, that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`formatInTimeZone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz#formatintimezone) from [`date-fns-tz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz) to output the date in UTC:

```
let { format  } = require('date-fns');
let { formatInTimeZone } = require('date-fns-tz');

var from = new Date();

console.log('Local time:', format(from, 'HH:mm, MMMM d, yyyy'))
console.log('UTC:', formatInTimeZone(from, 'UTC',  'HH:mm, MMMM d, yyyy'))
```

This will output something like:

```
 Local time: 08:23, December 6, 2022
 UTC: 16:23, December 6, 2022
```

Comment: If I want to format it using `MMMM d, yyyy`, can I change ur 3rd arg?

Comment: This worked well for me actually.

Comment: Oh yes, set the 3rd argument to the desired format.  I just added the HH:mm for illustration!